# Logging into website programmatically

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to log into this javascript? form using Java:

```
https://oasis.us.abnamroclearing.com/Login/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

I googled around and saw that I need to setRequestProperty?? and format in such a way to send the request. However I don't know what properties I need to set.

Say I just want to Login with username "apple" and password "banana".

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Would you like to start an interaction with this URL from Java code?

Comment: Checked and it is plain old reloading of the page, no JavaScript/Ajax. Also it's HTTPS so you will have to use SSL/TLS security in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using HTTPClient which is part of the commons-httpcomponents project now.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

There is an example of what you ask about:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java

This  tells about how to use SSL:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java